# The sum of odd numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

How to know the sum of odd numbers that between $1$ and $1000$ and their remainder when we divide them by $5$ is $3$.

Comment: There's formula for the sum of terms in arithmetic progression.

Comment: @Sgernesto Perhaps you could slightly expand your comment and post it as an answer. Meta: [Dealing with answers in comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments/1560#1560).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** 1. These are the numbers with $3$ as last digit: $3,\ 13,\ 23,\ 33,\ ...\quad\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
2. Pair them up so that the sum of all pairs is the same: Now it is $3\leftrightarrow 993$, $13\leftrightarrow 983$, etc.

Comment: but OP want $a_k = 3 \mod 5$

Comment: Ah, misunderstood. Sorry

Comment: Edited. $\ \ \!\!$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You are looking for odd number of the  form $5j+3$ for some integer $j$. Since $3,5j+3$ are odd, therefore $5j$ must be even. Thus $j$ must be even. Let $j=2i$. The numbers that you are looking for are of the form $10i+3$.such that $1\leq 10i+3\leq 1000$. Thus, $\frac{-2}{10}\leq i\leq \frac{997}{10}$. Can you evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^{99} 10i+3$

Comment: Yes .$49503$...

Comment: Don't forget the number 3, $0 \le i \le 99$.

Comment: @user64368 I will edit it

Comment: After evaluating i did not get the answer .I have choices the closet one is $49500$